# synchronized collection getter

Tags: java, multithreading, collections

IIUC, a `Collection` that is only ever accessed by a `synchronized` method should be thread-safe - is that right?

e.g.,

```
class Foo {
  private List<String> mList = new LinkedList<>();
  public synchronized List<String> getList() {
    return mList;
  }
}
```

Assuming this getter is used *exclusively* to access the list - all operations are via `getList()` - it feels like it should be thread safe to me - but I'm very happy to be told I'm wrong.

TYIA

Comment: No. You are returning a reference to your actual list. Anyone who got the list at some point can freely modify its contents in a non-thread-safe manner.

Comment: If you're returning the list then make it a simple method. Synchronization doesn't gonna do any magic here. And you're returning the reference of the list which can be modified by any one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would most likely not suffice as it simply returns a reference of the `List`; multiple threads would still be able to modify it concurrently, resulting in race conditions.  If you're looking for a fully synchronized `List`, then I suggest using an `ArrayList` wrapped with `Collections#synchronizedList`.

Comment: agree with the general statement, but not the recommendation.  instead of Vector, use ArrayList wrapped by Collections.synchronizedList().

Comment: @jtahlborn I agree, a `Vector` wouldn't be the best choice depending on what the OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: `Vector` has been obsolescent for nineteen years. That's a long time to still be recommending it. Don't use `Vector`.

Answer (score 1):

Better you go for **CopyOnWriteArrayList** if you have much more reads than writes, Because its Synchronized and also the Iterator of *CopyOnWriteArrayList* is **Fail-Safe** and doesn't throw *ConcurrentModificationException*.

You can also make the existing list synchronized using *Collections.synchronizedList(list)* but the Iterator will be *Fail-Fast*.